# Android - get USS memory allocation programmatically

Tags: android, memory-management, uss

I force this problem:

I need to know USS memory allocation (= how much RAM is allocated by your APP) for my app. I know, it is possible to get this info from "adb shell procrank", but I want to have it programmatically. Is there any way how to do it? Or any fully functional snippet? Up to know, I haven't been successfull and checking via adb shell is not comfortable and slow.

Comment: i know its old....but look at my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48885488/2553431)